# Eigenvalue and eigenvector $Av=λv$ , $A^{-1}v=\frac{1}{\lambda}v$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $A$ is invertible, and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, corresponding to some
eigenvalue $λ \in \Bbb R$. Show that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^{−1}$
, corresponding to the eigenvalue $µ = 1/λ$

Answer (score 3):

Once $A$ is invertible then $\lambda \ne 0$.

$$Av=\lambda v \Rightarrow A^{-1}(Av)=A^{-1}(\lambda v)\Rightarrow v=\lambda A^{-1}v \Rightarrow A^{-1}v=\frac{1}{\lambda}v$$

Comment: Note: since $A$ is invertible $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: @Piotr: Thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $v\neq 0$ and $Av=\lambda v$. Then,
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}v=\frac{1}{\lambda}Iv=\frac{1}{\lambda}(A'A)v=\frac{1}{\lambda}A'(Av)=\frac{1}{\lambda}A'\lambda v=A'v.
$$
So $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A'$. But $A'$ and $A$ have the same eigenvalues (because $\det(I-\mu A)=\det[(I-\mu A)']=\det(I-\mu A')$ for all real $\mu$), and so $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

---

**Without the use of determinant**: Suppose that $w\neq 0$ and $Aw=\lambda w$. We have
$$
\lambda^2||w||^2=(\lambda w)'(\lambda w)=(Aw)'(Aw)=w'A'Aw=w'(I)w=||w||^2.
$$
This implies $\lambda^2=1$ and so $\lambda=\pm 1$. In either case, $\lambda=\lambda^{-1}$ and so of course if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then it's trivial that $\lambda^{-1}$ ($=\lambda$) is also an eigenvalue of $A$.